# Ionic+ angular : Impossible to remove outline on <p> <a> or <div>

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I’m creating my application with a login page and I have my “Forgotten password ?”.

But I have already tried

and  with .class, :focus {outline: none} but there is still a yellow square around my item…
I don’t have this problem with my browser, only with my android application…

```
<a class="pass" [routerLink]="['/forgotten-pass']">Mot de passe oublié ?</a>
```

Someone has a solution about this issue ?

Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDOBy.jpg)

Comment: try to override :active

Comment: doesn't work, sorry

Comment: Can you provide more detail like a screenshot? it would be helpful since this is a UI issue.

Comment: @ChetanBansal I have edited my post, please find an image

Comment: This seems like a background color of some parent element that is showing up as border.. check if ion-content has this color.. or maybe you have this inside an ion-list... check the parent elements if any of those have this color as background.. the top corners are also of the same color so you can try inspecting those corners..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution :

```
:focus{
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0px;
 }
```